# How to render anychart to create the PDF using the WKHTMLTOPDF

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, anychart

I am using the below command to create a PDF for this anychart using the WKHTMLTOPDF.

`wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 2000 https://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Mekko_(Marimekko)_and_Mosaic_Charts/1000_Recordings_To_Hear_Before_You_Die.php test2.pdf`

But the chart/graph is not rendering in the generated PDF that is showed in the below screenshot generated.

Image of  PDF: 
[image: chart_not_render]

Right now, any chart creates the chart using the SVG. Can we change to another format to create the graph like canvas because may be WKHTMLTOPDF does not support SVG information?

Answer (score 0):

The AnyChart library is using GraphicsJS engine to generate SVG. It supports only SVG output. AnyChart provides export to PDF out-of-the-box. For this purpose, you can use `saveAsPdf()` chart function. Learn more about this function in [the API Reference](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.SeparateChart#saveAsPdf).

Comment: In my scenario, my one webpage shows the multiple charts so I need to get one PDF with all of those charts with that webpage content. So do you know that anychart is possible to get PDF of the whole webpage? If yes then how can I do? If you provide one example then it will better for me?

Comment: The default browser printing feature supports saving to PDF all the page content including SVG charts. Unfortunately, we can't suggest any solution for WKHTMLTOPDF as it's the third-party library and you should contact them about supporting SVG. Or you can use any other library that supports SVG.

Comment: Yeah, You are right sir.  Thanks for the clarification. I will find the alternative way to create PDF instead of using the WKHTMLTOPDF because it is not supported by the SVG format.